# Characterization of tangent space independent of parametrization

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a smooth $n$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n + d}$; $p \in \mathcal{M}$; $c : (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n + d}$ a differentiable curve with $c ((-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)) \subset \mathcal{M}$ and $c (0) = p$; $T_p \mathcal{M} = \operatorname{range} (D f_u)$ the tangent space at $p$, where $f$ is a parametrization of $\mathcal{M}$ with $f (u) = p$. Show that $T_p \mathcal{M}$ doesn't depend on the chosen parametrization $f$.

My attempt:

Let $f : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n + d}$ and $\tilde{f} : \widetilde{U} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n + d}$ both parametrize $\mathcal{M}$ around $f (u) = p = \tilde{f} (\widetilde{u})$. We have $\operatorname{range} (D f_u) = T_p \mathcal{M} = \operatorname{range} (D \tilde{f}_{\tilde{u}})$ and $\operatorname{rank} (D f_u) = \operatorname{rank} (D \tilde{f}_{\tilde{u}}) = n$. Hence, there is $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $v = D f_u \alpha$ iff there is $\widetilde{\alpha} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $v = D \tilde{f}_{\tilde{u}} \widetilde{\alpha}$ for $v \in T_p \mathcal{M}$, and the characterization of $T_p \mathcal{M}$ is thus independent of the parametrization.

This seems too simple indeed and I'm not sure whether I'm really proving the claim. Is there anything that I'm missing?

Comment: Why do we have ${\rm range}(Df_u) ={\rm range}(D{\tilde f}_{\tilde u}$?

Comment: You should consider for what purpose the curve $c$ is introduced.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of the tangent space at $p$ is
$$T_pM:=\{ v\in \mathbb R^n\mid \text{there exists $\varepsilon\gt 0$ and a diff. curve $c:(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\to\mathcal M$, s. th. $c(0)=p$ and $c'(0)=v$} \}$$

Thats why you should look how $v=c'(0)$ behaves under the change of parametrization $\phi:=\tilde{f}^{-1}\circ f:U\to\tilde{U}$. Use $u:=f^{-1}\circ c:(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\to U$.